Cauchy-Riemann equations to determine where f is differentiable
Let $f(z)=(\bar{z}+1)|z|^2$. Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to determine where f is differentiable.
My Solution
$f(z)=(\bar{z}+1)|z|^2\mathrm{,\ let\ }z=x+iy$
now
$f(z)=(x-iy+1)\left(x^2+y^2\right) = x^3+xy^2-ix^2y-iy^3+x^2+y^2$
$    =\left(x^3+xy^2+x^2+y^2\right)+i\left(-x^2y-y^3\right)$
The Cauchy-Riemann equations for differentiability:
$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$
Here we have:
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=8x^2+2x+y^2$
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=2xy+2y$
$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-2xy%$
$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-x^2-3y^2$
Clearly:
$u_x\neq v_y\Longleftrightarrow3x^2+2x+y^2\neq-\left(x^2+3y^2\right)$
and
$u_y\neq\ v_x\Longleftrightarrow2xy+2y\neq2xy$
and hence is not differentiable. I would like to have the reasoning here reviewed if possible.

You're talking about complex differentiability, correct? If so, please retag (via the edit button) your question from real-analysis to complex-analysis.

This site is not a proof-checking machine. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. That said, there are many mistakes in your attempt. The first one is "$f(z)=(x-iy+1)\left(x^2+y^2\right) $".

A general flaw in your attempt is: You are supposed to find those points $(x,y)$ where the CR equations hold, which involves solving some equations. Not just say that for general $x,y$, the formulae don't match.
